# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS doesn't boot after backup restore

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, php, backup

I have a dedicated web server running Ubuntu 14.04. 
I created a backup of the whole system (as described here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35087)

So I ran the command:

```
cd /
tar cvpzf backup.tgz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/backup.tgz --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys /
```

to backup nearly the whole system.

I then reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 (from my hosting admin panel) and tried to restore the backup file on my fresh and running system:

```
tar xvpfz backup.tgz -C /
```

The extraction happens without errors. When I try to reboot the server, it doesn't boot anymore. What can lead to this error?
Is there a better way to backup and restore a web server (I can't use LiveCDs of course)?
I really want to find a solution to restore especially Apache, PHP and MySQL from a backup file and not re-install every service including configurating every service. Thanks in advance!